# Embedding Playlist in Spotify App with HTML5

Tags: spotify, playlist

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but how do you get a playlist to show up inside an index.html for a Spotify App?  I've looked all over, and I couldn't find a clear way to do this.  I consulted the api-tutorial app and I tried looking over the API Docs.  Am I just missing it?  I experimented with  but that didn't work either.

Also, aside from that, is there a way for only single tracks from the app user's library be dragged into a box to be added to the displayed playlist in real time?  Or at least dragged into the box and the data be populated in some type of playlist in my personal profile at least? Or otherwise?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: My mistake. Looking at the [documentation for Spotify Apps API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/f19ff300f8.html), the `Player` class has the property `track` which gives the current playing track. The above URL shows how to use the observer interface to be notified when it changes.

Comment: So what would be an example of how to code a playlist into your app using html/javascript?

Comment: This question is about the Spotify Apps API, not the Web API. What the question is asking is completely possible.